# How to send and verify refresh token after expiration of jwt token without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jwt

What I have to do : when the user logs in , the page should stay as it is, until and unless the user logs out

Problem : I have generated JWT token  with expiry of 30 seconds . I get the access to secure page but after 30 seconds after refreshing the page gets closed because JWT expires . I have created a function for refresh token which produces and set cookie to JWT token , but how do I fire the endpoint automatically without touching URL bar or refresh button
What I mean is the refresh token should keep setting new cookie JWT without hitting other endpoint of refresh button

I saw the tutorial related it but I am not using react so not useful . I am using handlebars

Controller code

```
const {Registeration}=require('../database/model');
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs') ;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.signUp=async(req,res)=>{
    const User=new Registeration();
    User.name=req.body.name,
    User.email=req.body.email
    if(req.body.password===req.body.confirmPassword){
        User.password=req.body.password;
    }
    else{
        throw new Error('ircorrect password');
    }
    try{
        await User.save();
        res.redirect('/login');
        // res.status(201).send({message:"usser data saved"});
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err); 
        res.send(err);
    }
}

exports.login=async(req,res)=>{
    const User=new Registeration();
    const userData=await Registeration.findOne({email:req.body.email});
    console.log(userData);
    // console.log("isMatcch = "+isMatch);
    if(userData==={}){
        res.status(404).send({message:"user not found"});
    }
    else{
        const isMatch=await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,userData.password);
        if(!isMatch){
            res.status(400).send({message:"wrong password"}); 
        }
        else{
            const token=await userData.generateAuthToken()
            console.log(token);
            res.cookie("jwt",token,{
                path:'/',
                expires:new Date(Date.now()+1000*30),
                httpOnly:true,
                sameSite:"lax"
            });
            res.redirect('/user');
            // res.status(201).send({message:"user logged in",user:userData,token:token});
        }
    }
}
exports.verifyToken=async(req,res,next)=>{
    // const token=req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ','');
    const token =req.cookies.jwt;
    console.log(token);    
    const user=jwt.verify(token,"helloworld");
    if(!user){
        res.status(404).send({message:'invalid token'});
    }
    else{
        console.log(user)
        req.id=user._id
        // res.status(201).send({message:"token matched"});
    }
    next();
}
exports.getUser=async(req,res)=>{
    const user= await Registeration.findOne({_id:req.id});
    if(!user){
        res.status(404).send({message:"user not found"});
    }
    else{
        res.render('user',{
            data:user
        })
        // res.status(201).send({message:"user found",user:user});
    }
}
exports.refreshToken=async(req,res)=>{
    const token =req.cookies.jwt;
    if(!token){
        res.status(404).send({message:"couldnt find token"});
    }
    else{
        const user=jwt.verify(token,"helloworld");
    if(!user){
        res.status(404).send({message:'invalid token'});
    }
    else{
        res.clearCookie('jwt');
        req.cookie.jwt=" ";
        const token=jwt.sign({_id:user._id.toString()},'helloworld',{
            expiresIn:"30s"
        });
        res.cookie("jwt",token,{
            path:'/',
            expires:new Date(Date.now()+1000*30),
            httpOnly:true,
            sameSite:"lax"
        });
        req.id=user.id
        next();
    }
    }
}
exports.renderIndexPage=(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index');
}
exports.renderLoginPage=(req,res)=>{
    res.render('login');
}
exports.renderRegisterPage=(req,res)=>{
    res.render('register');
}
```

Routes

```
    const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const {signUp, login, verifyToken, getUser, renderIndexPage,renderLoginPage,renderRegisterPage,refreshToken}=require('../controller/signup and login controller');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');

router.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
router.use(express.json())
router.use(cookieParser());

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('homepage');
})
router.post('/register/data/recorded',signUp);
router.post('/login/data/recorded',login);
router.get('/user',verifyToken,getUser);
router.get('/index',renderIndexPage);
router.get('/register',renderRegisterPage);
router.get('/login',renderLoginPage);
//router.get('/refresh',refreshToken,verifyToken,getUser);// not working showing error
module.exports=router
```

Comment: FWIW, 30 seconds is a ridiculously short lifetime for an authentication token…

Comment: security? I guess , I am new to JWT so please can you help @deceze to show what I am doing wrong?

Comment: so refreshing the page before the 30 seconds is up works fine?

Comment: showing error @jaromanda

Comment: so, even refreshing the page just after login shows an error, so it's nothing to do with the token expiring ... what is the "error"? do we need to guess?

Comment: Half of the logic to handle tokens/refresh tokens is on the client side - of which, you've shown exactly 0 lines - making the JWT a http only cookie means that the client won't know when the token expires, so, won't know when to request a new token, and what refresh token to use to make such a request - you have a fundamental design flaw - unless your client code is doing *something clever* - but - can't see that so, can't say it would be doing anything *clever*

Comment: C:\Users\mahir\OneDrive\Documents\Auth JWT Youtube code\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:53
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt must be provided'));
                ^
JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided

Comment: @JaromandaX this is error when JWT expires and I refresh it

Comment: My frontend is made of handlebars , so there is no logic involved in frontend

Comment: The error is backend error?

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of this question what you're describing is impossible.

The HTTP(S) communication is closed after the user logs in / registers, meaning your user is no longer connected to your server, and cannot fire another request handler.

WHAY YOU CAN DO HOWEVER is adding logic to your frontend code that does another request to to refresh the token (you do another request after a delay on page load & on login (presumably the delay in what time it is until the token expires))

Comment: But the youtube person is using react and sending request after some interval through axios and he is getting refresh token without even hitting the endpoint manually or refreshing the page and the page is as it is after 30 seconds obv becoz of refresh token

Comment: SO how to use refresh token @marekvospel?

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough to know what is wrong. For the token to be refreshed a request to the refresh token endpoint must be made.

Comment: But how to make request automatically? @marekvospel